# tmux can't find TTY when run within read loop

Tags: bash, tmux, tty, source, read

I am trying to run tmux, from a sourced script (i.e., my `.bashrc`), within a `while read` loop. However, in doing this, tmux is unable to find the TTY and gives the following error:

```
open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

A minimal reproducible example, however spurious, is as follows:

```
while read -r _session; do
  tmux new-session -s "${_session}"
done < <(printf "%s\n" "$@")
```

(In my actual `.bashrc`, the `printf` is actually a `find` for files to `source`, one of which contains the `tmux` call.)

My presumption is that because the input that `read` is consuming is coming in on `stdin`, redirected from the process substitution, this blocks `stdin` for tmux.

I noticed that `read` can take a file descriptor as a parameter, so I tried to use that to get around the problem:

```
_tmp="$(mktemp)"
printf "%s\n" "$@" > "${_tmp}"

exec 3< "${_tmp}"
while read -ru 3 _session; do
  tmux new-session -s "${_session}"
done
exec 3<&-
```

This works, but it's really messy. Perhaps more importantly, however, is that -- as I alluded to -- what I want to iterate over is the output of `find` and, at this point, I'd be linewise iterating through a file of filenames, with all the problems that entails. The best resolution I can currently think of is using the `-print0` flag on `find`, then `read -d$'\0'`, to use a null-delimiter... Even messier!

(n.b., I can't use `find`'s `-exec` as I just want to `source` the files it finds, which must be done in the parent process, for obvious reasons.)

Is there a "nicer" way to iterate through files safely, to `source` them, *without* blocking `stdin` or `stdout`?

Comment: instead of passing the fd to `read`, pass it to tmux: `exec 3<&0; while read ...; do tmux <&3; done < ...`.

Comment: @mosvy That worked! There's a `source` inside my loop, rather than straight-up `tmux`, but sending it `&3` as `stdin` as a copy of the parent's `&0` did the job and it seems pretty clean. I'll accept this as an answer if you post it :) Thanks